# Can't connect with WIFI through nm-applet

Tags: networking, wireless, server, network-manager

I installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 with i3 on my laptop. The reason why I chose for the Server edition is because I wanted a minimal configuration. Additionally, I installed `network-manager` to help myself connect to WIFI connection. When I run `nm-applet` I get the overview of available WIFI connections. But when I want to connect with one of the WIFI connections I get the error-message `Failed to add new connection: (32) Insufficient privileges.`. I've tried [this](http://jeffhoogland.blogspot.nl/2012/05/howto-give-network-manager-sufficient.html) workaround, but unfortunately it didn't work  and I still get the same error-message.

PS I've also added my user-account to net-dev group.

Comment: The usual way to connect wireless in a server is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270901/ubuntu-server-12-04-2-wireless-connections/270974#270974